# AM Modulator Demodulator in Python

Tags: python, lowpass-filter, modulation, demodulation, numpy

I am trying to make a AM modem using Python Numpy and Matplotlib. I am successful in generating the AM Signal but I cannot demodulate it using a lowpass filter function that I made. The demodulation equation that I am using is;

$$A_{c}m(t)\cos(\omega_{c}t)\cdot 2\cos(\omega_{c}t)$$

My modulated output is this;
[image]

The demodulated signal is however this;
[image]

When it should have been this;
[image]

The lowpass filter that I am using is;
$$h(t) = \frac{\sin(2\pi Bt)}{\pi t}$$

Finally, this is my code;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)

message_freq = 50
message = np.sin(6.28*message_freq*t)
carrier_freq = 1000


class Filters():
    def LowPassFilter(self, cutoff):
        f = np.sin(6.28*cutoff*t)/(3.14*t)
        return f


class AmplitudeModem:
    def modulate(self, message, fc):
        c = np.cos(6.28*fc*t)

        mod = message*c
        return mod

    def demodulate(self, received_array, fc, fm):
        c = np.cos(6.28*fc*t)

        demod = 2*c*received_array
        baseband = demod #- self.modulate(Ac, received_array, 2*fc)
        return np.convolve(Filters().LowPassFilter(message_freq), baseband)

modulated = AmplitudeModem().modulate(message, carrier_freq)
demodulated = AmplitudeModem().demodulate(modulated, carrier_freq, message_freq)
```

Another problem that I am facing is that, I cannot plot the convolution (used in `demodulate()` function) with respect to time, due to their different dimensions.

Comment: (1) Make sure your sampling frequency is large enough (it looks like it is 10 Hz right now, but I could be reading your code wrong) and (2) you're missing a rectifier in the receiver.

Comment: but do i need a rectifier at all in this demodulation. As far as I know, a lowpass filter is enough to remove high frequency content from the spectrum of DSB-SC.

Comment: You do need it for DSB-LC: I misread your first equation and didn't realize you're doing DSB-SC with coherent detection. What about your sampling rate, is it high enough? Also, double-check your filter impulse response; I think you're missing a $B$ in the denominator.

Comment: The problem is solved now.

Comment: Himanshu, please consider adding an answer explaining what the problem was and how you solved it. You can even accept your own answer.

Comment: I've actually decided to downvote this question until you add that answer, as I think it takes away time from potential answerers and leads help-seekers astray if you don't explain how a problem was solved after you've gotten help in the shape of comments.

Comment: please see my code at https://github.com/hmnhGeek/Signal-Processing-and-Fourier-Transforms/blob/master/DSBS%20Modulation%20Scheme%20using%20Sinc%20Filter/dsbsc.py

Comment: Instead of convolution, I took the fourier transform on line 53 and multiplied the fourier transform of modulated signal on line 60. Then I took the inverse fourier transform to get the signal back with small distortion.

Comment: https://github.com/hmnhGeek/Signal-Processing-and-Fourier-Transforms/tree/master/DSBS%20Modulation%20Scheme%20using%20Sinc%20Filter

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I opened my dsp a/c today and I was surprised to find someone asking for solution. Sorry for delay @MBaz.

Comment: Please remove the downvote if possible.

Answer (score 2):

[image]This is wrong
Because if your carrier frequency is less than your message frequency, then you will have trouble in filtering .